# Excel VLOOKUP Reference showing blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

My formula works for Columns U, V and X, Y but not for W. Column W is showing blanks where is should show the VLOOKUP value?

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AD2),VLOOKUP(F2,'Raw Data'!E:Y,18,FALSE),AD2)
```

This one is filling the reference for AD2 if available, but the VLOOKUP is coming in blank.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AE2),VLOOKUP(F2,'Raw Data'!E:Y,19,FALSE),AE2)
```

This one is working fine and fills the data as it should.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ISBLANK will return false if there is a formula in the cell.  You may want `AE2<>""` instead for the IF criteria.

Comment: Thanks Scott. There isn't anything in the cell it's a Query from Microsoft Query, but has nothing in the cell. But your reference is working so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below, this might help:

```
=IF(AD2<>"",VLOOKUP(F2,'Raw Data'!E:Y,18,FALSE),AD2)
```

I think, the cells has blank spaces hence `VLOOKUP` is returning spaces.